# how to fit nlmer non-linear mixed model and have asymptote fixed?

Tags: r, mixed-model

I'm trying to compare the model where asymptote value varies over subject and the one that does not. I've fit the first (the one that varies) but can't seem to figure out the latter.

The first one is

```
m1 <- nlmer(weight~ SSlogis(Time, Asym, xmid, scal) ~ Asym|Chick, cw1, start=c(Asym =400,xmid = 11, scal = 3))
```

For the second one I tried

```
m2<-nlmer(weight~ SSlogis(Time, Asym, xmid, scal), cw1, start=c(Asym =400,xmid = 11, scal = 3))
Error in as.call(nlform[[lnl <- length(nlform)]]) : invalid argument list
```

it seems that to use `nlmer` I HAVE to include a random effect part. Is there a way to fit `nlmer` with asymptote value fixed?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

you can't fit the second one because it is not a mixed effect model. There are no random effects. Try using the nls function to fit it.